# Excel: use DropDown list to pull data when value select

Tags: excel

How to use the data from dropdown list on other work page?

On **page1** I have the data for drop list plus some values:

```
     A         B
1   NAME     VALUE  
2   Orange    12
3   Apple     4
```

On **page2** I use a dropdown list to display data from (page1) as NAME from cell A2:A4

```
      A        B         C         D
1    NAME     QTY      Price     TOTAL
2 [dropdown]   2      [value]    =B2*C2
```

The VALUE must be (12 or 4) depending on name i select.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This should be a question for superuser.com

Anyway, to create a drop down list, if you are on Excel 2010

Select A2 on page 2
Go to the top ribbon, Data -> Data Validation
Allow: set to 'List'
Source: input page1!A1:A3

for C2
the formula is

```
vlookup(A2, page1!A1:B3, 2, 0)
```